# como inserir object_list dentro do select do form no template do django 2.1

Tags: django, django-2.0

como que posso inserir uma lista do meu banco dentro do select do form?

template.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.id_departamento }}">Nome departamento</label>
    <select name="{{ form.id_departamento }}" required="" class="form-control" id="{{ form.id_departamento }}" multiple="">
        <option value="">------</option>
        <option value="{{ form.id_departamento }}">{{ form.id_departamento }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

models.py

```
class Funcionario(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Nome completo do funcionário')
    funcao = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Função na empresa')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='funcionario')
    departamentos = models.ManyToManyField(Departamento, related_name='funcionario')
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(
        Empresa, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia usar o ModelForm do Django, criando uma class para Funcionario, e não precisar ter que passar por estes problemas.

```
class Funcionario(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Funcionario
        fields = ['nome', 'funcao', 'user', 'departamentos', 'empresa']
        widgets = {
            'nome': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
            'funcao': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
            'user': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'hidden'}), 
            'departamentos': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
            'empresa': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

E no exemplo do seu template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="departamentos">Nome departamento</label>
    {{ form.departamentos }}
</div>
```

Por favor, me diga se isso resolveu seu problema.

Comment: não entendi direito a parte da class, crio um arquivo forms.py e incluo o codigo nele?